# How can I add a Finder Service that would use a single selected file, perform a shell script on it then display it as a dialog window?

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, automator, finder

How can I add a Finder Service that would use a single selected file, perform a shell script on it then display it as a dialog window?

I currently have Automator receiving files and folders within Finder then running an Applescript with the following:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Finder"

        set filename to selection
        set filename to quoted form of POSIX file filename
        set theCMD to "/usr/local/bin/exiftool "
        set theScript to theCMD & filename
        set theResult to do shell script theScript
        display dialog theResult
    end tell
end run
```

I continuously receive errors.  The intention is to show a dialog window with Exif metadata information for a single selected file within a Finder window.  I used brew to install exiftool to retrieve the data.

I'm new to applescript and can't figure out how to get this to work.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Automator service passes input items to the workflow, so you don't need to do anything else to get the selection.  In a **Run AppleScript** action the `input` parameter is a list, so you should pick a specific item or just loop though all the items:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with anItem in the input
        set anItem to quoted form of POSIX path of anItem
        set theResult to (do shell script "/usr/local/bin/exiftool " & anItem)
        display dialog theResult
    end repeat
    # return input
end run
```

Comment: Awesome. A side question... like in python with using the type command, is there an equivalent command in applescript that would show me the input variable's type?  List? string?

Comment: The `input` parameter will always be a list of the items from the workflow input and previous actions.  To get the type of an individual item in the list (they can be different), you can get its class property, e.g. `class of anItem`.